# How to ensure Topological Correctness

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

### Question:

I read through an enormous amount of material on topology and knot-theory in wikipedia, but I still am stuck at the following fundamental problem:

Given two representations of closed curves, how do you establish their "linkedness"?

So in a really simple example, given the equations for two circles in $\mathbf{R}^3$ how do I tell if they are a [Hopf link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_link) or disjoint loops?

### Background:

Myself and a conspirator have written a simulator for rope which minimizes stored energies by means of an iterative approach.  It works very well for a myriad of test cases, like a hanging segment, centenary, and we have used it to reproduce the shape of a [unit-knit](http://ej.iop.org/images/0964-1726/21/8/085011/Full/sms402678f3_online.jpg).

The problem comes when we tried to add rope-rope interactions.  In a nutshell, you have to go to fairly extreme lengths to ensure that the ropes do not pull through each other using the minimization process.  I believe this is not the way to go about things, so I am on the search of a more principled answer.

Comment: In general this is a very difficult problem. Distinguishing two links requires the use of so called [knot and link invariants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_invariant) and even then, there is still no known invariant which can distinguish all links up to ambient isotopy. In practice however, there are very robust invariants which can distinguish many links with small crossing number - and so as long as you are not working with horrible links with dozens of crossing numbers, an invariant such as Khovanov homology should be strong enough to distinguish between most different link-types.

Comment: Interesting.  There does seem to be some algorithms for computing the linking number, which I think is the property that defines the question, but I am not 100% sure.  Also, there is a layer of "Gauss map" in the associated equations I am having a hard time parsing out.  More reading going on here still.

Comment: I have had some limited success numerically integrating a double-line integral.  Mainly due to extensive help from my mathematician girlfriend.  I will post a flavor of what seems to work later today.

Comment: Hello @Felipe.  Thanks for the added bounty post.  I have a solution which results in a tough integral that when evaluated numerically seems to converge on the right answer (1).  I will post this stuff sometime this week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a generic 2-plane in 3-space and project your link onto it. Then use the idea in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number#Computing_the_linking_number.

To make it computationally feasible, you might have to approximate your link by a sufficiently close polygonal curve.

(This answers what I think is your main question, "Given the equations for two circles in R3 how do I tell if they are a Hopf link or disjoint loops?".)

EDIT: As Kevin Carlson points out in the comments, if the links can be disentangled, the linking number will be zero. If the linking number is zero, the links can be disentangled if each component is allowed to pass through itself (but not the other link), but possibly not if this not allowed (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_link for an example).

Comment: Note that while this will work to distinguish the Hopf link from the unlink it's not sufficient in general.

Comment: @KevinCarlson what do you mean by "in general" in this case?

Comment: To distinguish general links from each other-the OP did say the Hopf link/unlink case was a "really simple example."

Comment: @KevinCarlson I do believe this solves the problem for any link with two components (which can be well approximated by polygonal curves). For more components the problem becomes more difficult. Two-component links are indeed characterized by their linking number.

Comment: In a sense, yes-but linking number only characterizes two-component links if each curve is allowed to pass through itself via immersions. Ropes don't do that, so the OP may need stronger invariants.

Comment: @KevinCarlson ah yes - I forgot about this. However it seems solving that problem would be asking for (at least) ways of distinguishing the unknot, which I think is difficult.

Comment: This answer is correct.  Working through the Wiki equation for the the case of the two linked circles yields a definite integral.  Mathmatica can't find a symbolic solution, but numerical integration gives an answer of $1 \pm 1\times 10^{-8}$.  I am working on a Python embodiment of the calculation that I will post a gist to when I complete and validate it.

Comment: Hah, the Whitehead link is a great example of what makes this whole field complicated.  Much thanks!   Python to compute the linking number of a series of points (eventually curve fit) can be found here: https://github.com/o8ruza8o/knit/blob/master/KnotInvariants.py
Thanks for getting me started in Topology!